# Calibre doesn't start

Tags: release-loki

i'm using newest elementary os with my lenovo x250 and after i installed calibre from app center it just doesn't open. I click on the icon from Application meniu and nothing happens. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing it manually. This isn't really the fault of EOS, Calibre say themselves `Please do not use your distribution provided calibre package, as those are often buggy/outdated. Instead use the Binary install described below.` I'm guessing that's for a reason, and their old packages often don't work well, or aren't given back-ported updates.

Uninstall Calibre `sudo apt-get remove calibre` should work

Then [visit this link](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) to get a binary installer of latest version.

Hope the manual install works. If it still doesn't, let me know.